# Tasking VX, why is the predefined data file linked twice

Tags: assembly, infineon

Cannot figure out, why is my file (containing only DataFlash0 byte defines) linked into the output hex twice. I am compiling for Infineon TC1797 with Tasking VX compiler.

Besides the program, I have a file named data_flash_bank_0.asm, which only includes predefined data bytes.

Compiler properly places it at the expected address of 0x8FE00000, which is the data flash 0 in hardware.

What is wrong is that the same code appears within the program as a second copy, wasting space and not wanted.

All the setting in the project properties seems fine, 'delete duplicate' enabled.

To illustrate the problem, I made one VERY SMALL project, where there are only 3 files: test.c function with main(), short assembly function reading the data flash, and the data flash predefines.

test.c:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 extern void * loop_36(void); // call the main assembly function

 int main(void)
 {
    loop_36();
 }
```

assembly function jozo.asm:

```
 .sdecl "PFLASH", CODE
 .sect  "PFLASH"

 .global loop_36

 loop_36:
     movh.a     a4, #0x8FE0
     mov16      d2, #0      ; Move
     lea        a2, 0x3F    ; Load  Effective Address

 loop:
     ld16.w     d15, [a4+]4 ; Load Word
     or.ne      d2, d15, #0 ; Not Equal Accumulating
     loop16     a2, loop    ; Loop
     ret16                  ; Return from Call

 .end
```

and the actual predefined bytes area giving me the problem, file data_flash_bank_0.asm:

```
 .sdecl ".data.dflash0", DATA AT 0x8FE00000
 .sect ".data.dflash0" ; new edit: trying .rodata instead of .data

 .byte 0xF2, 0x45, .... 32k more bytes

 .end
```

Map file:
(the last line is what I expect, but the 2 lines above it, also length 0x8000, I do not want)

```
 +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Chip        | Group    | Section                                   | Size (MAU) | Space addr | Chip addr  | Alignment  |
 |     ========================================================================================================================|
 | spe:pflash0 |          | .text._Exit.libc (191)                    | 0x00000004 | 0x80000008 | 0x00000008 | 0x00000008 |
 | spe:pflash0 |          | .text._c_init.libcs_fpu (98)              | 0x0000000c | 0x8000000c | 0x0000000c | 0x00000002 |
 | spe:pflash0 |          | .text._c_init_entry.libcs_fpu (97)        | 0x00000132 | 0x80000020 | 0x00000020 | 0x00000020 |
 | spe:pflash0 |          | table (202)                               | 0x00000030 | 0x80000154 | 0x00000154 | 0x00000004 |
 | spe:pflash0 |          | .text._ldmst_clear_byte.libcs_fpu (95)    | 0x0000002e | 0x80000184 | 0x00000184 | 0x00000002 |
 | spe:pflash0 |          | .text._ldmst_copy_byte.libcs_fpu (96)     | 0x00000044 | 0x800001b2 | 0x000001b2 | 0x00000002 |
 | spe:pflash0 |          | .text.cstart..cocofun_1 (14)              | 0x0000001a | 0x800001f6 | 0x000001f6 | 0x00000002 |
 | spe:pflash0 |          | .text.cstart.__init_sp (12)               | 0x0000001c | 0x80000210 | 0x00000210 | 0x00000002 |
 | spe:pflash0 |          | .text.cstart._start (13)                  | 0x000001c2 | 0x8000022c | 0x0000022c | 0x00000002 |
 | spe:pflash0 |          | .text.sync_on_halt._sync_on_halt (61)     | 0x0000008e | 0x800003ee | 0x000003ee | 0x00000002 |
 | spe:pflash0 |          | .text.sync_on_halt._sync_on_halt_end (60) | 0x0000000c | 0x8000047c | 0x0000047c | 0x00000002 |
 | spe:pflash0 |          | .text.test.main (84)                      | 0x0000000c | 0x80000488 | 0x00000488 | 0x00000002 |
 | spe:pflash0 |          | [.data.dflash0] (203)                     | 0x00008000 | 0x80000494 | 0x00000494 | 0x00000001 |
 | spe:pflash0 |          | PFLASH (5)                                | 0x00000014 | 0x80008494 | 0x00008494 | 0x00000001 |
 | spe:dflash0 |          | .data.dflash0 (1)                         | 0x00008000 | 0x8fe00000 | 0x0        | 0x00000001 |
```

Comment: Hard to tell without additional information. Where is the duplicate located and what seems to be referring to it? Can you create a minimal reproducible example for us to review, with complete code and build output? Particularly the map file.

Comment: doynax: thank you, I updated the question, is it clear now?

Comment: The apparently redundant copy in program memory might be necessary so the C runtime library can initialize the DFlash memory with bytes you've provided.

Comment: @EmbeddedGuy: Somewhat, though the map is still a bit scant. I have limited knowledge of the toolchain but at a guess the variable is unintentionally being allocated as initialized data to be copied from program FLASH into "RAM" at the specified address at start-up. Try using the `.rodata` segment prefix instead.

Comment: @Ross I do not have room for that, and do not need an initialization. That is a separate memory and when it gets programmed during chip programming, there is no need to initialize it?

Comment: @doynax: Now it is going in the right direction. With .rodata added, the map file show the predefined data only in the proper section (the one where it occupied space in program area is gone).
Now one thing has to be solved instead: the program stopped working, DEBUG says in red No source available for "", so at this moment I cannot step through the code.

Comment: @EmbeddedGuy: Tricky. My first attempt would be to check out what the C compiler emits for an equivalent variables as a reference, presumably through some combination of `#pragma romdata`, `__far` and `@`.

Comment: @doynax: please make the .rodata as answer, I will mark it as proper answer. The other thing is simply another question

Comment: When I remove the code optimization in C, the program can be debugged now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tasking VX linker infers the segment type and other metadata based on the name of a section. The `.data` in `.data.dflash0` signifies *initialized* data. That is read-write RAM memory for which an initial state gets copied from ROM during star-up. The second copy in `PFLASH` which you are seeing is this initialization copy.

The solution is to use the `.rodata` section prefix instead, which is intended for read-only data.

Effectively the linker has been given an absolute address and told to initialize it and so must assume that it is backed by RAM. Aside from wasting space it is of course also a bad idea to have the CRT start-up attempt to write into FLASH.

Incidentally the `.data` and `.rodata` are not magic hard-coded names. A linker script, in this case the default one, includes group directives indicating which memory area each of the individual sections is to be located into along with attributes such as `nocopy` to control the initialization.